# How do I get Scanner to pick out a keyword from user input?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

If the user input is "it's cold outside" instead of just "cold", the program moves (like it's supposed to do) to the else statement.  How do I get it to run and pick out keywords without knowing user input?

```
   System.out.println("I am doing well, thank you!  How's the weather today?");
    String s = scan.nextLine();
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("cold") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("freezing")) {
            System.out.println("You'd better bundle up");                
        } else {
           System.out.println("Stay cool");
        }
```

Comment: Use `contains()` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (s.contains("cold") || s.contains("freezing"))
```

Here `contains()` method searches the sequence of characters in the string. It returns true if the sequence of char values is found.

**Note:** `equalsIgnoreCase` method compares two strings on the basis of the content of string irrespective of their case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) to check if the keywords are in the input as follows:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("I am doing well, thank you!  How's the weather today?");
String s = scan.nextLine();
if (s.indexOf("cold")>-1 || s.indexOf("freezing")>-1) {
     System.out.println("You'd better bundle up");                
} else {
     System.out.println("Stay cool");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use contains and toLowerCase. For example:

```
  System.out.println("I am doing well, thank you!  How's the weather today?");
    String s = scan.nextLine();
        if (s.toLowerCase().contains("cold") ||  s.toLowerCase().contains("freezing")) {
            System.out.println("You'd better bundle up");                
        } else {
           System.out.println("Stay cool");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  s.toLowerCase().contains is just what I was looking.  Thanks again